# Electrical engine calculations

Tags: ruby, validation

The `ElectricalEngine` class responds to the `horsepower` message. Because efficiency is calculated in percent a programmer can mistakenly initialize it with an integer instead of a float.

```
class ElectricalEngine
  attr_reader :volts, :current, :efficiency

  def initialize(volts, current, efficiency)
    @volts, @current, @efficiency = volts, current, efficiency
  end

  HP_IN_WATTS = 746
  def horsepower
    (volts * current * efficiency) / HP_IN_WATTS
  end
end

puts ElectricalEngine.new(240, 90, .6).horsepower # correct
puts ElectricalEngine.new(240, 90, 60).horsepower # buggy
```

How would you handle this scenario?

1. Do nothing. It's the programmers responsibility to know the right datatype.
2. Rename `efficiency` to `efficiency_as_float` to make it clearer.
3. Rename `efficiency` to `efficiency_as_percent` and adjust `horsepower`'s calculation.
4. Write a custom `efficiency` method to check the datatype and convert it accordingly.
5. Check `efficiency` type and raise an error if it's not a float.
6. Other

Solution four might look like this. Of course this conversion can happen in the `initialize` method too, but I think this is cleaner.

```
def horsepower
  (volts * current * efficiency_as_float) / HP_IN_WATTS
end

def efficiency_as_float
  if efficiency.is_a?(Integer) # what if 1 is passed in instead of 1.0?
    efficiency / 100.to_f
  else
    efficiency
  end
end
```

Solution 5 would look something like this:

```
def initialize(volts, current, efficiency)
  raise "Efficiency must be a float" unless efficiency.is_a?(Float)
  @volts, @current, @efficiency = volts, current, efficiency
end
```

Should `ElectricalEngine` own the responsibility of converting incorrect datatypes?

Comment: [tag:srp] is a meta tag and I have removed it. If you are concerned about violating the single responsibility principle, please mention that concern in your question.

Comment: On a related note: I have rejected your proposed tag-wiki edit. The reasoning is the same as provided by RubberDuck already. For more information, see [the relevant meta-discussion](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/should-we-do-something-about-our-meta-tags)

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I've just wasted 5 minutes trying to figure out what "burninate" means :D

Comment: Can't you just check if `efficiency` is a number between 0 and 1.0?

Comment: @KristofClaes I could, yes. But I classify that under the "raise an error" solution. The implementation details are not that important at this stage. I'm interested more in "the spirit" of the approach.

Comment: Perhaps you should add "7. Check that `efficiency` is between `X` and `Y`. Let's say efficiency is always between 0.6 and 0.9, and the user intends to enter an efficiency of `80%`.  If the user enters `80` or `80.1`, that's easy to catch, but what if the user inadvertently enters `0.08`? In this case, raise an exception!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say pick #1: Do nothing (except, as m_x says, use `to_f`). But, if you really, really want to do *something*, pick #5: Raise an error. Specifically, I'd recommend raising a [`RangeError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/RangeError.html) with a helpful message.

```
raise RangeError, "efficiency must be between 0 and 1" unless (0..1).cover?(efficiency.to_f)
```

As for this:

> Because efficiency is calculated in percent a programmer can mistakenly initialize it with an integer instead of a float.

Yes, it can happen (I've made such mistakes myself), but using a 0..1 float is the more common approach (in my experience). It's usually only spreadsheets that deal with percentages as 0..100; in most programming (and math) contexts, "percent" means some 0..1 number. So calling it `efficiency_as_percent` could cause the opposite effect: People passing a 0..1 float where an int is required.

Either way, the efficiency isn't *specifically* percentage (although you might render it as such); it's just a ratio. A factor. Hence floats make more sense, as they allow you set a more precise value than 0..100.

Of course, you have to be a bit pragmatic about all this, so you don't end up implementing a strict type in a dynamically-typed language. For instance, you *could* also check `volts` and `current` - e.g. they probably shouldn't be negative. But then it quickly becomes a huge headache.

You might also ask, "well, what if I *want* to calculate the horsepower of an over-unity engine?". Well, you can't, if `efficiency` can't go above 1.0. But in a sense, it's just algebra. You've got a formula, and you can plug whatever you want into it. Whether it makes sense to plug certain values in doesn't change the math. From a practical standpoint, a 200% efficiency engine is of course impossible, but you can still do the math just fine. Heck, even a perfect, 100% efficiency engine is impossible. Sooo should you only allow 0...1 (half-open range)? If you don't allow 1.0 itself, then how close a value *do* you allow? 0.9? 0.99999?

Similarly, a zero-efficiency engine sounds like a mistake, so should you point that out too? And so on and so on...

Anyway, I'd be ok with checking `efficiency`, but I wouldn't bother with it myself. Leave it to the programmer to do things right or suffer the consequences. GIGO: Garbage In, Garbage Out.

Comment: I see where you are going with this. It makes perfect sense. If I want to check for this, then why not check other things too? It seems like an arbitrary choice to focus on efficiency because *I believe* it's easier to make an mistake. Thanks.

Comment: "You've got a formula, and you can plug whatever you want into it" >> I think every math graduate reading that will choke to death :D. Anyway, good point here,  and I'll add : if you really care about type semantics, just create an Efficiency class that responds to to_f _and_ raises a range error when initialized with a value out of bound (or silently constrains the value inside accepted range). This way there's two distinct steps : checking if the values are meaningful, and combining values within a formula.

Comment: @m_x Well, in that case: I accept no responsibility for any choking-related issues experienced by math grads :) But really, the calculation _will_ produce a result - of some kind - for any combination of (real) numbers, but perhaps _physics_ grads will choke (again: not responsible!) if you start talking about >100% efficiency :) Anyway, good point there, about making it a more explicit 2-step process.

Answer (score 6):

my two cents : use duck-typing.

```
@efficiency = efficiency.to_f
```

... if it quacks like a float, then it is a float. This allows to leverage ruby's awesomeness with things like :

```
class EfficiencyProfile 
  def initialize(some_data, value)
    @data = some_data
    @efficiency_value = some_value 
  end

  def to_f 
    @efficiency_value.to_f
  end 
end 

e = EfficiencyProfile.new(some_big_chunk_of_data_about_engine_performance, 42)
ElectricalEngine.new(1,2,e) # would work without a complain
```

Dynamic typing sure is dangerous, but you have to embrace it if you want to benefit from it.

Checking the type explicitly is an half-arsed solution, because :

- it is cumbersome, and you will never be as good at it than, say, a C compiler is
- it will completely remove the sole benefit from dynamic typing : flexibility.

Comment: I'm not clear on the benefits derived from the example you provided. To me it looks like extracting the efficiency into its own class and using dependency injection. Am I correct?

Comment: not exactly. My example is not really clear : what i'm trying to say is that you only need to care that what you get responds to to_f. That way, if you want to use anything other than a Float, it is still possible. Duck typing is better explained with non primitive types : one good example is the core StringIO class, that mimics a "real" IO object - you can use it with any lib that demands an IO object (responds to #read, #write, #close, etc.) because those libs just assume that if what you pass to them quacks like an IO, then it is an IO.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type efficiency is, all that matters is that efficiency is between 0 and 1. This is also the message that the user wants to see: not that they used the wrong type, but that their input was out of bounds. This would also protect against someone accidentally passing 80.5, thinking they were passing 80.5%.